# Add two edge loops aroung selected edge loop (hard surface modeling)

Tags: modeling, edges

Does anyone know if there is an addon to add two edge loops adjacent to an existing edge loop, to make "creases" while using a subsurface modifier? I don't wanna mark sharp edges or mark creases, I want to manually (by this addon) add 2 edge loops close to a selected, exsiting edge loop. Ideally this addon would allow me to choose an offset, and also apply these pair of edge loops to as many edge loops I select. I don't think this exists already in Blender so I'm guessing I need to code that??

Just to make sure I expressed myself correctly, here's what I want to do:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the *Bevel* operator for this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> by default, no addons needed.

You can control how many additional loops are added from the operator options panel <kbd>F6</kbd> by default.

[image]