# How to increase the Space between two Edge Loops?

Tags: edges

[image]

I created two edge loops and during creation (or after) I want to move them apart. I can move them together during creation but I wanted them a certain distance from the existing edges on either side of the newly created edge loops.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57259/how-to-slide-a-vertex-group-to-make-new-edge-loop and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74634/slide-two-edge-loops-away-from-each-other/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75590/add-two-edge-loops-aroung-selected-edge-loop-hard-surface-modeling/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit like 3DS 'slide' and 'pinch'.. the nearest match in Blender is to cut **1** central loop, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> 'Offset edge slide' that loop, sending two parallel loops off in each direction. (Don't forget to check the tool's options in the 'last operator' panel).

You can then dissolve the original loop.

Comment: Perfect thanks - not sure how I mark this as answered

Comment: @barkest    If an answer works for you, you can click the tick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Slide* tool. Just select the edge loop, then press **G** key twice and move it with the mouse. While sliding, the edge loop is automatically aligned to the nearest boundary edge loop.

You can press **E** key to set the boundary edge loop you want to align to, and **F** key to switch between the two boundary edge loops.

Use the numpad to type the sliding value, so you can slide the two edge loops uniformly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Just tried that but I am not sure I can do both at once. Does that mean I have to do them individually? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, you have to do them individually. But if you use a numeric value (type it during sliding) the edge loops's offset is the same.

Comment: thank you and the ability to use the num pad is great - thanks